# Delphi 11 VCL TTrackBar does not have Tracking property, events fire on each tick change

Tags: delphi, events, tracking, vcl, delphi-11-alexandria

In Delphi FMX, `TTrackBar` has two events for tracking changes - `OnChange` and `OnTracking`.
Those two events only do the same thing when `Tracking` is enabled (by default). Disabling the `Tracking` will make it so that `OnChange` is only fired after the user is finished.

My problem is that using Delphi 11 for a VCL application, the `Tracking` property does not exist, and the events fire with each change/tick instead at the end (resulting in sending multiple messages).

I would prefer only the end change / last value), according to this older post:

[Delphi TTrackBar doesn't have on complete event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39151832/)

Comment: @Ives: I don't quite understand: I just checked in both Delphi 4 (25 years old) and Delphi 10.4 (fairly new), and in neither of these versions does `TTrackBar` have an `OnTracking` event.

Comment: Anyhow, if you want to reduce the number of times your event is fired, a standard trick is to use a `Timer: TTimer` with `Timer.Enabled = False` and `Timer.Interval = 500` (say) which you reset each time there is a change in the control (`Timer.Enabled := False; Timer.Enabled := True`). Then let its `OnTimer` handler start with `Timer.Enabled := False` and then the thing you want to do. Being notified "when the user is finished" isn't quite straight-forward, because the user may interact with the control using (1) a point-device like a mouse, (2) a keyboard, (3) speech accessibility UI, etc.

Comment: The equivalent FMX TTrackBar has an OnTracking event, but the poster explicitly mentions VCL.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, in Delphi 11 there actually is an OnTracking event.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, please cross check in Vcl.ComCtrls from the latest Delphi 11. There is an OnTracking event. On the other hand there is no Tracking property.

Comment: @UweRaabe I don't have Delphi 11. But the docs I looked at didn't show on `OnTracking` event. Turns out I was looking at the Sydney docs, but in the   Alexandria docs it is listed now. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`TTrackBar` in VCL does not have an event when tracking is finished. However, the underlying [Win32 Trackbar control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/trackbar-control-reference) *does* send such notifications.

It sends [`WM_HSCROLL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-hscroll--trackbar-)/[`WM_VSCROLL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-vscroll--trackbar-) messages (depending on its orientation) to its parent window, where the `LOWORD(wParam)` is set to `TB_ENDTRACK`. You can subclass the parent window to handle these notifications.

It can also send a [`TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/trbn-thumbposchanging) notification to the parent window, where the `lParam` holds a pointer to a [`NMTRBTHUMBPOSCHANGING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-nmtrbthumbposchanging) struct, whose `nReason` field is set to `TB_ENDTRACK`. You can subclass the `TTrackBar` itself to catch `CN_NOTIFY` messages to handle this notification.

Comment: Thx for all the good feedback (I'm not allowed to vote yet) I handled it with listening to an Application Events in combination with WM_LBUTTONDOWN , I only trigger the action (originally in the trackbar.change) when the button is up. Seems to work fine.